# Validation ERRORs in my form

Tags: java, php, html

When i leave my text boxes empty , there will be errors that will be displayed beside my text boxes.Example: type is required. I have a file name trade form result.php which defines all my validations and price.php which inserts in to database.It is going into the first if statement which allows inserting into database if there are no errors. But in fact, i submitted an empty form which will prompt all my errors. It is just not happening. It submits the form to price.php( insert) even if there are errors. All answers appreciated

```
<?php 
$selection  = '';
$type       = '';
$size   = '';
$bidprice  = '';
$offerprice     = '';
$stoploss       = '';
$takeprofit     = '';
////////////////////////////////
$Error  = '';
$selectionError     = '';
$typeError  = '';
$sizeError = '';
$bidpriceError  = '';
$offerpriceError = '';
$stoplossError  = '';
$takeprofitError    = '';

$message = '';

$errors = array();

$noErrors = true;

$haveErrors = !$noErrors;

require_once('validations/tradeformresult.php');

if ($noErrors && $userArriveBySubmittingAForm) {

    require_once('price.php');// INSERTION

    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>\n"; 
    echo "alert('Trade is successfully executed!');\n"; 
    echo "</script>"; 


///////////MESSAGE///////////////// 
}
 else if ($haveErrors && $userArriveBySubmittingAForm) {

    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>\n"; 
    echo "alert('Please re-enter your parameters.);\n"; 
    echo "</script>";

    $message = "\t\t" . '<font color="red">Fail!</font><br />' . "\n";
    $message = $message . "\t\t" . 'Validation errors : <br />' . "\n";

    $message = $message . "\t\t" . '<ol>' . "\n";

    foreach ($errors as $key=>$errorMessage) {
        $message = $message . "\t\t\t" . '<li>' . $errorMessage . '</li>' . "\n";
        if ($key == 'selection') {
            $selectionError = $errorMessage;
        }
        if ($key == 'type') {
            $typeError = $errorMessage;
        }
        if ($key == 'size') {
            $sizeError = $errorMessage;
        }
        if ($key == 'bidprice') {
            $bidpriceError = $errorMessage;
        }
        if ($key == 'offerprice') {
            $offerpriceError = $errorMessage;
        }
        if ($key == 'stoploss') {
            $stoplossError = $errorMessage;
        }
        if ($key == 'takeprofit') {
            $takeprofitError = $errorMessage;
        }

        }   
        $message = $message . "\t\t" . '</ol>' . "\n";      

 }
 else if ($userArriveByClickingOrDirectlyTypeURL) { // we put the original form inside the $message variable
    $newTitle = 'The link is broken';

    $h1Title = '';

    $message = '';
}
?>
```

**Trade Form Result**

```
$userArriveBySubmittingAForm = !empty($_POST);

//  user arrives by GET
$userArriveByClickingOrDirectlyTypeURL = !$userArriveBySubmittingAForm;


// check if user arrives here via a POSTBACK

if ($userArriveBySubmittingAForm) {


    $selectionNotGiven = empty($_POST['selection']);

    // if name not given
    if ($selectionNotGiven) {

        // we add new error into $errors
        $errors['selection'] = "Symbol is required";
    }
    $typeNotGiven = empty($_POST['type']);

    // if name not given
    if ($typeNotGiven) {

        // we add new error into $errors
        $errors['type'] = "Type is required";
    }
    $sizeNotGiven = empty($_POST['size']);

    // if name not given
    if ($sizeNotGiven) {

        // we add new error into $errors
        $errors['size'] = "Size is required";
    }
    $bidpriceNotGiven = empty($_POST['bidprice']);

    // if name not given
    if ($bidpriceNotGiven) {

        // we add new error into $errors
        $errors['bidprice'] = "Bid Price is required";

        $offerpriceNotGiven = empty($_POST['offerprice']);

        // if name not given
        if ($offerpriceNotGiven) {

            // we add new error into $errors
            $errors['offerprice'] = "Offer price is required";

            $stoplossInvalid = ($_POST['stoploss'])>($_POST['offerprice'])||($offernodecimal-$stoplossnodecimal)< 200
            ||($_POST['stoploss'])<($_POST['bidprice'])||($bidnodecimal-$stoplossnodecimal)< 200;

            if ($stoplossInvalid) {

                // we add new error into $errors
                $errors['stoploss'] = "Stop Loss is invalid";
            }

            $takeprofitInvalid = ($_POST['takeprofit'])<($_POST['offerprice'])||($takeprofitnodecimal-$bidnodecimal)< 200
            ||($_POST['takeprofit'])>($_POST['bidprice'])||($offernodecimal-$takeprofitnodecimal)< 200;

            if ($takeprofitInvalid) {

                // we add new error into $errors
                $errors['takeprofit'] = "Take Profit is invalid";
            }

        }
        $noErrors = (count($errors) == 0);

        // haveErrors is the opposite of noErrors
        $haveErrors = !$noErrors;

        if (!empty($_POST['selection'])) {
            $selection = $_POST['selection'];
        } // end if name NOT empty

        if (!empty($_POST['type'])) {
            $type = $_POST['type'];
        } // end if name NOT empty

        if (!empty($_POST['size'])) {
            $size = $_POST['size'];
        } // end if password NOT empty

        if (!empty($_POST['bidprice'])) {
            $bidprice = $_POST['bidprice'];
        } // end if password NOT empty

        if (!empty($_POST['offerprice'])) {
            $offerprice = $_POST['offerprice'];
        } // end if sex NOT empty

        if (!empty($_POST['stoploss'])) {
            $stoploss = $_POST['stoploss'];
        } // end if sex NOT empty

        if (!empty($_POST['takeprofit'])) {
            $takeprofit = $_POST['takeprofit'];
        } // end if diploma NOT empty

    }
}
// end if no errors

/** end of proceed as normal **/

// @TODO code expected here to assign the variables in Ex1-5/registerform.php lines 10-17
// remember that $interests is an array, so we need to check $_POST['interests'] for empty and also    ????


/** end of proceed as normal **/

?>
```

Comment: What is the content of `tradeformresult.php`?

Comment: Tradeformresult contains all the validations , i will edit the question with the code

Comment: I would strongly suggest using JavaScript to perform some validation on the client-side. It'll make your page feel more responsive. May I suggest Validity, a great JS library for helping with this: https://github.com/afincha/validity

Answer (score 0):

You appear to have a couple of misplaced closing braces in `tradeformresult.php`. As a result, you're only setting `$noErrors` if no bid price is given. From what I can see, the last 2 braces should be moved up like this:

```
if ($bidpriceNotGiven) {

    // we add new error into $errors
    $errors['bidprice'] = "Bid Price is required";
} // <===== Moved from below

$offerpriceNotGiven = empty($_POST['offerprice']);

// if name not given
if ($offerpriceNotGiven) {

    // we add new error into $errors
    $errors['offerprice'] = "Offer price is required";
} // <===== Moved from below
```